# Why the threading.timer doesn't execute every 1ms in my code?

Tags: multithreading, timer

I set the threading.timer interval time to 100ms. From the console output, the time interval is about 1.6s. Why doesn't write a line in console output every 100ms? What I want to do is a 1ms accurate timer, so I can use it in my code to simulate PLC real time system.

```
Module Module1
Class StateObjClass
    ' Used to hold parameters for calls to TimerTask 
    Public SomeValue As Integer
    Public TimerReference As System.Threading.Timer
    Public TimerCanceled As Boolean
    Public GLO_TICK As Long
End Class

Public StateObj As New StateObjClass
Public long_Temp1 As Long
Public int16_temp1 As Int16

Sub RunTimer()

    StateObj.TimerCanceled = False
    StateObj.SomeValue = 1
    Dim TimerDelegate As New Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf TimerTask)
    ' Create a timer that calls a procedure every 2 seconds. 
    ' Note: There is no Start method; the timer starts running as soon as  
    ' the instance is created. 
    Dim TimerItem As New System.Threading.Timer(TimerDelegate, StateObj, _
                                               0, 1)
    StateObj.TimerReference = TimerItem  ' Save a reference for Dispose.
    Dim a As Boolean = False

    Dim state As Int16
    While True ' Run for ten loops.
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)  ' Wait one second.

        Select Case state
            Case 0
                If a Then
                    long_Temp1 = StateObj.GLO_TICK
                Else
                    a = True
                    long_Temp1 = StateObj.GLO_TICK
                    Console.WriteLine("a=" & a & Now)
                End If
                state = 1
                Exit Select
            Case 1
                Calculate_Interval(long_Temp1, int16_temp1)
                If int16_temp1 > 100 Then
                    a = False
                    long_Temp1 = StateObj.GLO_TICK
                    Console.WriteLine("a=" & a & Now)
                    state = 2
                End If
                Exit Select
            Case 2
                Calculate_Interval(long_Temp1, int16_temp1)
                If int16_temp1 > 100 Then
                    a = True
                    long_Temp1 = StateObj.GLO_TICK
                    Console.WriteLine("a=" & a & Now)
                    state = 1
                End If
                Exit Select
        End Select

    End While

    StateObj.TimerCanceled = True  ' Request Dispose of the timer object.
End Sub

Sub TimerTask(ByVal StateObj As Object)
    Dim State As StateObjClass = CType(StateObj, StateObjClass)

    If State.TimerCanceled Then    ' Dispose Requested.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done  " & Now)
        State.TimerReference.Dispose()
    End If

    System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(State.GLO_TICK)
End Sub
Sub Main()
    RunTimer()
    Console.Read()

End Sub

Function Calculate_Interval(ByVal IntervalStart As Long, ByRef Interval_ms As Int16) As Int16
    Interval_ms = Convert.ToInt16(StateObj.GLO_TICK - IntervalStart)
    Return Interval_ms
End Function
```

End Module

Comment: Basic bug is that you assume the Timer will tick with 1 millisecond precision.  It doesn't, it cannot tick faster than the operating system interrupt rate.  By default 64 ticks per second, shortest interval you can count on is therefore 15.625 msec.  So your simulation runs about 16 times too slow, just what you see when you observe 1.6 sec in the console.  Using Environment.TickCount fixes that problem.  Code is also pretty dangerous with lots of threading race bug opportunities, a PLC avoids that danger by only updating state at the end of a scan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is there a way to implement a milisec timer? I really want to find a solution.

Comment: Environment.Tick works fine. Could you explain why there's lots of threading bug risks? Thanks in advance!